# Gilgit-Baltistan is disputed territory, then how is it that Pakistan administers that area?

Tags: india, united-nations, geopolitics, pakistan, kashmir

According the the [Instrument of Accession (Jammu and Kashmir)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_of_Accession_(Jammu_and_Kashmir)) signed by the **ruler of the princely state of Jammu and Kashmir**, Maharaja Hari Singh, **the entire state of Jammu and Kashmir is a part of India**, **Gilgit-Balitistan** included.

Tribal invaders sponsored by the Pakistani army then invaded the northwestern parts of Jammu and Kashmir, known as Azad Kashmir and Gilgit-Balitistan. The region has been illegally occupied by Pakistan ever since. [The Line of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_Control) is between India and Pakistan.

Acording to [UNSC Resolution of 1947](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_47) the territory is part of the **disputed Kashmir**

**Then how pakistan can make administrative in that area ?**

Comment: I am not entirely sure what the question is here. As you say, these territories are _de facto_ part of Pakistan, so the Pakistani government is going to administer them. The strength of the Indian claim to them doesn't really come into it.

Comment: The region has been illegally occupied by Pakistan.

Comment: I have linked some wiki url's, Pakistan is going against United Nations Security Council Resolution 47.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_47

Comment: Because they can :) What kind of answer do you expect? This site is not really an appropriate place to make a statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the historical claims to Kashmir from India and Pakistan?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2341/what-are-the-historical-claims-to-kashmir-from-india-and-pakistan)

Answer (score 4):

> Then how pakistan can make administrative in that area ?

Simply because they currently are in control of the area; this will be true of most disputes over territory - the party in current control believe that by rights* it is theirs (or else they would not be claiming it) and so will run the administration of the area.

*or by might, but it boils down to the same thing in the end

Comment: I means UN will come in middle ? Because Pakistan broke the law. so what will be UN's action as per it's constitution ?

Comment: @AdityaShah that's an entirely different question, but the resolution was a set of recommendations so Pakistan aren't breaking the law by not following it. (The invasion is a separate matter.) even if it had been binding, politics would come into whether anyone would supply the troops needed to enforce any such resolution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_of_Accession_(Jammu_and_Kashmir)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_47

Comment: @AdityaShah very nice. I believe there was a war fought over that, and an eventual cease-fire declared, leaving Pakistan to administrate those areas on their side of the cease-fire line.